# How can I get the serialized HTML fragment, using libxml and C

Tags: c, libxml2

I have very simple xml

```
<root>
    <node>some value</node>
</root>
```

How can I get the serialized HTML fragment, using libxml and C. I mean same as you can get using `outerHTML` in JS (`document.getElementsByTagName("node")[0].outerHTML`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [xmlNodeDump](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDump). Or if you want to print node out to file/stdout, then use [xmlElemDump](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlElemDump)